# How can I reference a substr without creating a new object?

Tags: c++, string, hashmap, hashtable

I have several strings 2000 - 3000 characters in length and I would like to hash every substring with length X to an unordered_multimap. Thus I am traversing through each string character by character to determine each hash. The substr function creates a new string and so does inserting a std::pair into the multimap. I'd like to avoid as much as possible. Is there a way to work around this?

Pseudo Code Example:

```
For each String str:
    For i to str.length - hashlength
        hash = str.substr(i, hashlength) //A
        unordered_multimap.insert({{hash, i}}); //B
```

I would prefer to have parts A and B use as little constructor calls as possible.

Comment: Enable C++11 and declare hash as `string&&`

Comment: If hash is a `std::string` you can reuse in the loop then you call use `hash.assign(str.begin() + i, str.begin() + i + hashlength)` and at least save one allocation.

Comment: If you want to store it in a map, then atleast **one** construction is necessary

Comment: @texasbruce How would that help?

Comment: You could store a pair of iterators

Comment: @neilkirk the OP wanna fewer constructor call. Binding rvalue tp rvalue reference avoids constructor.

Comment: @texasbruce substr returns a new string, which results in a dynamic allocation. I don't see how storing it in string&& will prevent that.

Comment: @neilkirk if u use string, it will call move or copy constructor/operator. if u use `string&&`, there is no constructor call.

Comment: @texasbruce Substr will call constructor. When putting in hash, it can use move already. That is cheap.

Comment: @NeilKirk all I am saying is that binding a rvalue to a rvalue reference is the cheapest you can get, and it is cheaper than move construction too. I don't understand what you are trying to argue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several libraries that allow you to do this. Such as [`boost::string_ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html) and [`llvm::StringRef`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html).  A similar class, [`string_view`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3921.html) (upon which `boost::string_ref` is based), is in the works for future standardization. If you don't want to download another library, the class is fairly simple to implement. It is little more than a `const char*` to indicate the start of the sub-string, and an integer to indicate the length (alternatively, another pointer to indicate the end point), plus some utility functions.

A common thing to be aware of with all these classes, is that you need to make sure that the source string remains alive and unmodified (or at least, ensure no reallocations happen) for as long as the referencing object is used. In other words, treat them with the same care as you would a pointer (since that's essentially what they are).

Comment: Would this require rewriting the hashcode function?

Comment: @whytheman: Yes, unless you use a library which provides a hashing function for you. I believe `llvm::StringRef` does, and I'm sure (or at least I hope) that `string_view` will when it is standardized.

Comment: string_view was already included on c++17 then that is the best option